# Creating binary data from text values in a column in R

Tags: r

I have a really large data set that I need to create new columns for based on text strings from other columns, and put them in a binary format.
I have a person ID column and a set of 99 "Diagnosis Codes" that contain a text string that corresponds to a particular health condition.

Sample of Original Data

| Person ID | Diagnosis Code 1 | Diagnosis Code 2 | Diagnosis Code 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | N18.3 | V34.2 | E73 |
| 11 | F35.9 | X29 | D4.0 |
| 12 | G27.2 | J05.1 | J60 |

I need to get the data into this format....

| PersonID | N18.3 | V34.2 | E73 | F35.9 | G27.2 | (plus all other codes) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | etc |
| 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | etc |
| 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | etc |

I have tried transposing, tabluation, so many other different ways and nothing seems to work.  I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

We could reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then reshape back to 'wide' with `pivot_wider` while specifying the `values_fn` as `length` and `values_fill` set to 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -PersonID) %>%
    select(-name) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from= value, values_from = value,
       values_fn= length, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  PersonID N18.3 V34.2   E73 F35.9   X29  D4.0 G27.2 J05.1   J60
     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       10     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2       11     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
3       12     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

---

Or using `recast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df1, id.var = 'PersonID', PersonID ~ value, length)
  PersonID D4.0 E73 F35.9 G27.2 J05.1 J60 N18.3 V34.2 X29
1       10    0   1     0     0     0   0     1     1   0
2       11    1   0     1     0     0   0     0     0   1
3       12    0   0     0     1     1   1     0     0   0
```

---

Or use `base R` with `table` after `unlist`ing the columns other than the first one

```
table(rep(df1[[1]],  ncol(df1)-1),  unlist(df1[-1]))
      D4.0 E73 F35.9 G27.2 J05.1 J60 N18.3 V34.2 X29
  10    0   1     0     0     0   0     1     1   0
  11    1   0     1     0     0   0     0     0   1
  12    0   0     0     1     1   1     0     0   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PersonID = 10:12, DiagnosisCode1 = c("N18.3", 
"F35.9", "G27.2"), DiagnosisCode2 = c("V34.2", "X29", "J05.1"
), DiagnosisCode3 = c("E73", "D4.0", "J60")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: These are all very useful, I especially like the reshape function, I'll be using that very much in the future!!

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `melt` and `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(melt(setDT(df),id.vars = 'PersonID'),PersonID ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)

#   PersonID D4.0 E73 F35.9 G27.2 J05.1 J60 N18.3 V34.2 X29
#1:       10    0   1     0     0     0   0     1     1   0
#2:       11    1   0     1     0     0   0     0     0   1
#3:       12    0   0     0     1     1   1     0     0   0
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much, saved me many hours of grief!